# Cannot see google maps on android when I upload it for release (works in debug), trying to get SHA1 from my created keystore

Tags: android, google-maps

(Mac)
I created a keystore with alias and password with the same name (projectOne) and when I try to get the SHA1 from that created keystore and put it on my created google console maps I have trouble getting the SHA1 out.

I type this in the terminal but it does not let me access the keystore.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/ projectOne.keystore -alias projectOne
```

It says this (roughly translated):

```
Invalid option/Unauthorized: projectOne.keystore
```

Now I use the SHA for debug:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono\ for\ Android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

And this does not work when I try to "release" it. So I assume I have to get the SHA1 from my own created keystore but as I mentioned above. It says it is an invalid option/Unauthorized option.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/MD5_SHA1/) you need to first find the `.keystore` file that your `.apk` was signed with. The keystore used will depend on if your app's .apk package was created as a debug build, or if it was packaged with a different `.keystore` file.

For builds that you have signed with your projectOne.keystore file, you need to substitute your own values for the .keystore file, keystore password, and alias name from when you created the keystore file.

You can follow these [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/obtaining_a_google_maps_api_key/) and [forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37874/can-sign-apk-on-windows-but-failing-on-os-x-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect) which suggested to verify that the alias or password you use is correct.